# what is the most accurate way to query target mobile device resolutions with CSS @media?

Tags: css

If I use `max-device-width` does that include landscape mode?

Say I use it to detect iPhone 4, should I use `max-device-width: 640px` or `960px`? I need to get 3 resolutions: `480x320`, `960x640` and `854x480`. What would be the best way to query for them using `@media`

My take was:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 854px) {}
@media screen and (min-device-width: 855px) and (max-device-width: 960px) {}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is some Css to help you:

```
// target small screens (mobile devices or small desktop windows)  
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {  
  /* CSS goes here */  
}  

/* high resolution screens */  
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),  
             (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2),  
             (min-resolution: 300dpi) {  
  header { background-image: url(header-highres.png); }  
}  

/* low resolution screens */  
@media (-webkit-max-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
             (max--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),  
             (max-resolution: 299dpi) {  
  header { background-image: url(header-lowres.png); }  
}
```

Have a read through this link it should solve your problem

http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/using-mobile-specific-html-css-javascript

Comment: Please at least include the essential parts from that article (people come here from search engines too).

Answer (score 5):

The `device-width` and `device-height` [media query features](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) (along with their `min/max` prefixes) essentially provide the screen resolution of a mobile device.

On an iPhone, regardless of the generation or presence of a Retina display `device-width`:

- Is always `320px` in portrait mode
- Is always `480px` in landscape mode

Using JavaScript, we can get the viewport's width:

```
<script>
    // Alert Mobile Device Width
    alert(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
</script>
```

Media queries targeting 320px screens still work on iPhone 4, due to Mobile Safari utilizing a 'device to pixel ratio' density of 2.

For example, when the iPhone 4 browser viewport is equal to the device width, 1 CSS pixel actually translates to 2x2 device pixels.

> There is a distinct difference between a device (screen) pixel and a pixel that we typically define in CSS. For a detailed explanation, see [High DPI Web Sites](http://www.webkit.org/blog/55/high-dpi-web-sites/).

This is largely good news for Mobile Web Developers, as very little needs to be done to mobile stylesheets for iPhone 4 and Retina displays — since device pixels are translated to CSS pixels automatically.

On a related note, iOS 4 (and iPad with iOS 3.2) introduced *orientation* to help with detecting orientation change. As soon as the iPhone/iPad detects the orientation changing, it will execute any CSS matching the respective media query.

Consider the following [orientation detection example](http://f.cl.ly/items/211Y3t3h1m0y0M0K2Z29/media-query.html):

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    .box { background: red; }
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    .box { background: yellow; }
}
```

[image: iPad Orientation Detection]

The same functionality can be accomplished (or combined with) using `width` and `device-width` to trigger portrait vs. landscape modes:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Portrait Mode */
    .box { background: red; }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-device-width: 480px) {
    /* Landscape Mode */
    .box { background: yellow; }
}
```

The [orientation media feature](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation) is `portrait` when the value of the `height` is greater than or equal to the value of the `width` — otherwise `orientation` is `landscape`.

As illustrated, `max-width` and `min-width` are updated when you rotate the screen — so `max-width` in *portrait mode* becomes `max-height` in *landscape* mode.

---

For reference, here's the screen size and resolutions of the iPhone and iPad:

> **iPhone 2G, 3G, 3GS** (3.5" diagonal, 163 ppi)
>       Portrait: 320x480
>       Landscape: 480x320
>
> **iPhone 4, 4S** (3.5" diagonal, 326 ppi)
>       Portrait: 640x960
>       Landscape: 960x640
>
> **iPad 1, 2** (9.7" diagonal, 132 ppi)
>       Portrait: 768x1024
>       Landscape: 1024x768

Comment: what do you mean by `Media queries targeting 320px screens still work on iPhone 4, due to Mobile Safari utilizing a 'device to pixel ratio' density of 2.`?

Comment: With the advent of high pixel density displays (i.e. Apple's Retina display at 326 ppi) the pixel itself is now a relative unit. A 'CSS pixel' indicates a point on a virtual pixel grid. This has led to the definition of a Density-Independent Pixel (dip). So a width of `320px` will render the same size on all iPhones (due to iOS scaling up the 1x1 pixel to 2x2 using a `device-pixel-ratio` of `2.0`). When iOS scales the elements in physical size to fit the iPhone 4 screen, they take up the same amount of space as the elements drawn on the iPhone 3GS, but use four times the number of pixels.