# Mobile web design for various devices

Tags: mobile, mobile-website, pixel, dpi

I'm new to developing sites for mobile devices and looking for some insight from those that know more than I do. Since starting this project I have learned that there are a lot of differences between the iphone and the Android, which I believe is mostly due to the pixel density of the devices. I have incorporated some device queries into my CSS to determine the pixel density of the user's device before the pages are displayed.

I am continuing to try to tweak the CSS to adjust for the different variables on various devices, but what works on one does not work on another (ie: font size, line height, etc).

My question is this...what are the *variables* that determine the way my site is displayed on different devices and operating systems? I know of only one and that is *pixel density*. Are there others, aside from device width and height? Does aspect ratio need to be targeted?

Any insight you can give me is greatly appreciated.

The site I am working on can be viewed at http://m.usci.westondev.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine how the site looks on different devices, you need to set `devices breakpoints`
a good start is media queries like bellow

```
    /* 600px/16px = 37.5em */
    @media all and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    ...
    }
    /* 940px/16px = 58.75em */
    @media all and (min-width: 58.75em) {
    ...
    }
    /* 1300px/16px = 81.25em */
    @media all and (min-width: 81.25em) {
    ...
    }
```

a more detail tutorial can be found [here](http://pugetworks.com/blog/2011/04/css-media-queries-for-targeting-different-mobile-devices/) and this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8745075/623546) also give some pretty

Comment: Yes, and I actually do understand that part of it. But the media query example that you have above is strictly based on width. What other factors should I be considering? What about pixel density?

Comment: there are a lot of other factors when doing responsive design, a few or them are using fluid media and a fluid grid, to influence the elements layout the way you want for each devices. with media queries you could also target very specific devices (for instance define a style only for iphone4S and another just for the Iphone5 - tho it might be extra work), also use pixel density for typography and image rendering see http://menacingcloud.com/?c=highPixelDensityDisplays